# Metronic (4.5.2) setup background images in LoginPage when I use ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, metronic

This is an example `loginPage` in Metronic Sample document. I copy this code to my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. But `LoginPage` does not show background images.

This is the Metronic example loginPage:
[image: Metronic example loginPage]

Code in ASP.NET MVC 5:
[image: Code in ASP.NET MVC 5]

Run result:
[image: Run result]

Markup:

```html
    <div class="col-md-6 bs-reset">
        <div class="login-bg" style="background-image:url(~/Scripts/assets/pages/img/login/bg1.jpg)">
            <img class="login-logo" src="~/Scripts/assets/pages/img/login/logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the network tab in the browser dev tools - do you see any errors? Also, are there any browser console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `background-image` like the following:

`background-image:url(Scripts/assets/pages/img/login/bg1.jpg)`

Without the `~/` part in the path.

Comment: I modify my code according to your answer but the page still dont show images.